# Why webkit browsers can't highlight selected texts in this site?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, highlighting

Website: http://clandestinoangusto.it/

Hi, can anybody explain why WebKit browsers are not able to highlight selected texts in the above given website? Its working fine with IE and FF,But chrome and safari just showing the highlight cursor, but not able to select text.

Probably it's something about CSS, but I can't fix it at all.

Thankyou.

Comment: What is your **problem**, **requirements** and **goal**? Explain more clearly

Comment: It might just be me but grey text on a different grey or black background makes me click that red X in the upper right really fast.

Comment: My goal is to let webkit users be able to highlight texts in this site.

Comment: @fatlox *highlight* or may be *select*?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Yes, sorry. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this from body style

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but the following code will let you style the highlight:

```
/* webkit, opera, IE9 */
::selection { background: tomato; }
/* mozilla firefox */
::-moz-selection { background: tomato; }
```

Might come in useful.